# Tabbing environment with special characters

Tags: accents, tabbing

Inside a `tabbing` environment, certain symbol combinations (such as `\'`) are reserved for defining tabs and increasing/decreasing indentation of the text. However, I would like to include special characters inside a `tabbing` environment with special characters such as `\'{c}` and `\'{e}`. Is there any way to "escape" these special character combinations?

Below is an MWE, where for instance I'd like to write "Adiós" instead of "Adios". But if I use `Adi\'{o}s`, the text only shifts and no accent is put on the "o".

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
Hello ~~~~ \= Hi\\
 \> Adios
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

By the way: at some places I read that `\o'` is supposed to do the trick here, but it just converts the "o" to a "ø" and adds the ' afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the occasional oddity, I'd suggest boxing the content first and then using the box inside `tabbing`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\tabbox}
\begin{document}
\savebox{\tabbox}{Adi\'os}
\begin{tabbing}
Hello ~~~~ \= Hi\\
 \> \usebox{\tabbox}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, use a UTF8 input encoding directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
Hello ~~~~ \= Hi\\
 \> Adiós
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

You can also save the original definitions you're interested in, like `\'` and `` \` ``:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\textacute\'
\let\textgrave\`
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
Hello ~~~~ \= Hi\\
 \> Adi\textacute{o}s
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and even giving me several options to choose from! The last solution seems to be the "cleanest" to me -- just give the command another name, and call that name instead. That works well, thanks!